# Amazon Connect Contact Flow - TTS voice not set in all scenarios

Tags: text-to-speech, amazon-connect

I am setting TTS in a module in Amazon Connect. When I make a change (in my case via Lambda) the TTS voice correctly propagates to various places in the IVR flows, such as the default whisper pre live agent connection announcing the queue the call is landing from "Basic queue".

However, when a customer ends up in a in-queue callback the TTS voice setting is lost and default is used.

Is this a bug, or do I need to be setting TTS manually in multiple places?

Setting it once should be enough.

The flows in use are all default flows e.g IB Whisper (which works) and the OB in-queue callback (doesn't work for either customer whisper, or agent whisper). Uses Default Outbound flow.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make sure you choose the voice again in your outbound whisper flows. The callback is a different contact from the original call even though they are linked.

Comment: Why is voice set per contact. Why not globally. Surelythat's the dominant use case?

Comment: I couldn't tell you why, but contacts use the default voice for your language if you don't set it. If you want something different, you set it in the contact flow. It's only one block at the beginning of each flow. I wouldn't be opposed to AWS adding an instance-wide setting for default Polly voice per language.